# How to rebuild a gtk.stack

Tags: python, python-3.x, gtk, gtk3

I need help in figuring how to rebuild an element of a gtk.stack.

Assuming that the child is a gtk.box containing information which it may have to be rebuilt in many ways, as the reconstruction should be done?

```
def refresh_take(self):
    self.take_container.destroy()
    #Reconstructed container
    self.take_container = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL)
    #Reconstructed Top label
    hbox = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.HORIZONTAL)
    label = Gtk.Label("For take:", xalign=0)
    self.take_container.pack_start(label, False, False, 10)

    get_ready = self.database.get_tomas_ready()
    listbox = Gtk.ListBox()
    listbox.set_selection_mode(Gtk.SelectionMode.NONE)
    #Reconstructed First list
    counter = 0
    for list_element in get_ready[0]:
        self.create_med_dialog(list_element[0])
        row = Gtk.ListBoxRow()
        hbox = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.HORIZONTAL, spacing=50)
        row.add(hbox)
        vbox = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL)
        hbox.pack_start(vbox, True, True, 0)
        if list_element[4] in range(10):
            minutes = '0' + str(list_element[4])
        else:
            minutes = list_element[4]
        tempo = (str(get_ready[1][counter]) + ":" + str(minutes) + "H")

        Pill = Gtk.Label(tempo + "\t" + list_element[0] , xalign=0)
        vbox.pack_start(Pill, True, True, 0)
        if counter == 0:
            button = Gtk.Button(label="Take")
            self.demanded_pill = list_element[0]
            button.connect("clicked", self.demand_pill)
            hbox.pack_start(button, False, True, 0)

        listbox.add(row)

        self.take_container.pack_start(listbox, False, False, 0)
        counter = counter + 1

    #The second label is reconstructed
    hbox = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.HORIZONTAL)
    info_label = Gtk.Label("Next Pill:", xalign=0)
    self.take_container.pack_start(info_label, False, False, 10)

    get_next = self.database.get_tomas_next()
    listbox = Gtk.ListBox()
    listbox.set_selection_mode(Gtk.SelectionMode.NONE)
    #The second list is reconstructed
    counter = 0
    for list_element in get_next[0]:
        row = Gtk.ListBoxRow()
        hbox = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.HORIZONTAL, spacing=50)
        row.add(hbox)
        vbox = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL)
        hbox.pack_start(vbox, True, True, 0)

        if list_element[4] in range(10):
            minutes = '0' + str(list_element[4])
        else:
            minutes = list_element[4]
        Pill = Gtk.Label(list_element[0], xalign=0)
        vbox.pack_start(Pill, True, True, 0)
        label = Gtk.Label(str(get_next[1][counter])
        + ":" + str(minutes) + "H")
        hbox.pack_start(label, False, True, 0)
        listbox.add(row)
        counter = counter + 1

    self.take_container.pack_start(listbox, False, False, 0)
    self.take_container.set_visible(True)
    self.stack.add_named(self.take_container, "Takes")
```

When my stack refreshes, all disappear, but I want that they create the labels again, after destroy.

Comment: Please try to rephrase that, maybe with code example. It's unclear want you want to do.

Comment: This is still very hard to understand. You talk about a Stack but your example has no stack widget. Is that snippet the whole function?

Comment: I dont want to change the stack itself, I want to rebuild one of itschilds.

Comment: Please try to be more precise. As an example, if the problem is that the label you create is not visible, you could say "the label I create in the code below never appears in the UI".

Comment: Yes, I want refresh all my labels and listbox in container, but when I execute the function, my labels and listbox disappear and don't appear again, as it was supposed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code snippet, it looks like you are not adding the widgets you create into any containers. Unless you do that somewhere else `listbox` and `self.take_container` are created but never added to any containers.

Comment: You want to do at least `self.take_container.show_all()` instead of set_visible(True)... There could still be problems with the Stack visible child after that: I wouldn't remove the child itself as it might affect how the stack operates, but instead remove and add just the children of take_container.